# MariaDB no longer shipping with auth_socket.so?

Tags: mariadb

MariaDB still has lots of [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/) regarding unix socket authentication. Version 10.3 ships with `auth_socket.so` in the `/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/` directory.

But it's gone in version 10.4.26 and later. Was it renamed or deprecated? What is the upgrade path for people who had been using unix socket auth?

Comment: Check: `In MariaDB 10.4.3 and later, the unix_socket authentication plugin is installed by default, and it is used by the 'root'@'localhost' user account by default. See [Authentication from MariaDB 10.4](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-from-mariadb-104/) for more information.`, see [Authentication Plugin - Unix Socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/). Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2Suwbeyj).

Comment: The page you linked says `In MariaDB 10.4.3 and later, the unix_socket authentication plugin is installed by default`, which suggests the plugin has been removed from your installatiion only.

Comment: @shadow: No, it hasn't  been removed, it's statically linked.

Answer (score 2):

When socket authentication for unix sockets became default (in MariaDB 10.4) the plugin type changed from dynamic to static, which means the plugin is statically compiled into server.

If you need it as a shared plugin (e.g. if an application tries to install the plugin via INSTALL SONAME), you need to rebuild it from source:

```
cmake .. -DPLUGIN_AUTH_SOCKET=DYNAMIC
```